# Problems with transition on flex: 0, but still working on flex: .0001?

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox, transition

While working on a little project, I stumbled into having to transition from `flex: 1`to `flex: 0`. It took me a while to understand that it was only for this that the result was broken. After testing a bit I've found out that `flex` is transitionable, but not if one of the values it has to go through is 0.

For example, from `flex: 1` to `flex: .0001` works, and almost gives me the same result, but it seems like a hack to me. I'd like to understand why is that, because I could not find nor think of any good explanation for this.

```css
.container1, .container2 {

  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}

.container1 > div, .container2 > div {
  
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  
  transition: flex 1s, -webkit-flex 1s;
  -webkit-transition: flex 1s, -webkit-flex 1s;
  
  height: 100%;
}
.container1 > div:hover {

  
  flex: 0;
}
.container2 > div:hover {

  flex: .00001;
}

.a { background-color: blue }
.b { background-color: red }
```

```html
<p> hover to activate the transition </p>

<p> doesn't work with a final flex of 0 </p>
<div class="container1">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>

<p> works with a final flex of .000001 </p>
<div class="container2">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

I'm using Chrome 43, haven't tested on other browsers yet.

Can you give me a valid explanation on why this is or whether this is a bug or not?

Comment: Works in Firefox nightly, aurora, and stable. Doesn't work "properly" in chrome 43.

Comment: @AwalGarg dang, thanks! Now let's see if this was intentional by google then, or how to elegantly fix this. I really hate that .0001

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flexbox spec author here.

Originally, the spec mandated that you couldn't transition to/from flex:0.  This is because there was a huge difference between 0 and non-zero 'flex-grow' values.  For example, if your flex container is 1000px wide and your flex item is 100px wide, flex:0 keeps it at 100px while flex:.001 used to make it grow to the full 1000px.  (There was nothing else for it to compete for the space with, so it would take the whole thing.)

A year or two ago I fixed this, so flex values less than 1 don't try to take *all* the space they can; instead, they try and take a corresponding fraction of the available space.  In the previous example, if the item was flex:0.5, it would only expand to 500px wide (half the space) and leave the rest empty.  This new behavior gives us nice continuous behavior all the way down to zero, so there's no longer a discontinuity, and we can now allow transitions between any flex values.

So yeah, it's a Chrome bug; we haven't updated our behavior to the newer spec text.  Please report it!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I'll try reporting it as you suggested